Fantasy book about a group of teens who escaped from a prison guarded by ogres, then found a civilization of elves
I remember that a group of teens (don't know the species) were kept in a prison guarded by ogres (I think). These teens would eventually escape into a desert. Only a few would survive and then find the edge of a civilization of elves (maybe) and would train a lot. I don't remember much else.

In roughly which year did you read this? And do you recall anything about the cover?
